# Fullcalendar with JSON feed returning eventSource in extended form

Tags: fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm using the excellent fullcalendar by arshaw with Angular UI and right now I'm having a problem with eventSource objects in extended form not rendering when fetched as JSON feeds.

The data is fetched using the following code in the controller:

```
$scope.events = [   
  '/api/v1/users/104/events?format=cal&type=9',
  '/api/v1/users/104/events?format=cal&type=10'
];
$scope.eventSources = $scope.events;
```

When the JSON feed returns an array with event objects it actually works:

```
// returned by - /api/v1/users/104/events?format=cal&type=9
[
  {
    url: "/#/events/86893",
    start: "2013-03-15",
    title: ": Event - 86893"
  },
  {
    url: "/#/events/31348",
    start: "2013-03-27T09:30Z",
    title: "Event - 31348"
  }
],
// returned by - /api/v1/users/104/events?format=cal&type=10
[
  {
    url: "/#/events/86899",
    start: "2013-03-25",
    title: ": Event - 86899"
  },
  {
    url: "/#/events/31349",
    start: "2013-03-17T09:30Z",
    title: "Event - 31349"
  }
]
```

However I would like to specify some options along with the event data, for example different colors for different JSON feeds. Hence I settled for the API to return the event source in its [extended form](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) . This is what it API returns.

```
// returned by - /api/v1/users/104/events?format=cal&type=9
{
  events: [
    {
      url: "/#/events/86893",
      start: "2013-03-15",
      title: "Event - 86893"
    },
    {
      url: "/#/events/31348",
      start: "2013-03-27T09:30Z",
      title: "Event - 31348"
    }
  ],
  color: "#ff9900",
  allDayDefault: false,
  ignoreTimezone: true
},
// returned by - /api/v1/users/104/events?format=cal&type=10
{
  events: [
    {
      url: "/#/events/86899",
      start: "2013-03-25",
      title: "Event - 86899"
    },
    {
      url: "/#/events/31349",
      start: "2013-03-17T09:30Z",
      title: "Event - 31349"
    }
  ],
  color: "#3366FF",
  allDayDefault: false,
  ignoreTimezone: true
}
```

Unfortunately this format isn't rendered when fetched as JSON. When fetching the extended format I changed the eventSources assignment somewhat to look like this:

```
$scope.eventSources = [ $scope.events ];
```

If I cut and paste the raw JSON response (with the event source in its extended form) from the API straight into the eventSources method it works. Isn't it possible to consume the event source in extended form when it is returned as a JSON feed?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the eventSource being returned from the API is not where the extended form options should be used, but rather in the event functions used as the eventSource's.

The documentation states that the extended form should be used inside of the Json object used to call the API.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

If the API was too return the extra options for the events, then it would need to set each one individually.

Currently in this post, The only place I see where the extended options are called is from the returned api data.

I think this should be the other way around. And the calendar should know about the extended form before it even requests the data at all. This would mean the server will not need to return any extra options and the calendar will organize the event objects by feed and extended options.

If you could post a plunk, then we could nail this.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. I updated the code example a bit to clarify a bit. As you see the color option is different for each of the event sources. I will try to get a plunk up tomorrow or the day after.

Comment: I've made a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/XWEhZWEwsYbjeFnTEDw3?p=preview I still think you are right about that one cannot include extended event sources with options. I'm new to angular but I figure that I could use a service to request and return the data? Thanks for your time.

Comment: So all I did was make the feed object utilize the extended form and changed the events.json file to just return a pure events array and the extended form works per feed object like hypothesized.                http://plnkr.co/edit/7L0MZ72FfNCwrKsg5Dcs?p=preview

Comment: thanks! Actually I just solved it by using an angular service that returns the event objects in extended form. In other words, full calendar doesn't have to resolve the JSON URLs at all but will be spoon fed with event sources in extended form. A key to get it working was setting isArray to false in the service, something like: `query: { method:'GET', params: { userId: 0, typeId: 0 }, isArray: false }`